# C# function synchronization

Tags: c#, java, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# version of java's synchronized keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541194/c-version-of-javas-synchronized-keyword)

Is there an equivalent in c# to the java *synchronized* keyword for functions? I wish to synchronize a function rather than just a block...

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541194/c-version-of-javas-synchronized-keyword

Comment: Thank you, didn't find it before.