# What is the equivelent of the synchronize block in Java, in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, session, equivalent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# version of java's synchronized keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541194/c-version-of-javas-synchronized-keyword)

I know that when working with a session in Java, you were always supposed to surround use of the session with a synchronized block incase the user would load your page with two browsers at the same time.

Is there an equivalent keyword/block in C# for doing the same thing?

Comment: Duplicate - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541194/c-version-of-javas-synchronized-keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) statement or decorate a method with the [`[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute.aspx) attribute to allow access to this block/method only from a single thread at a time.