# Locking a Static Method in C#

Tags: c#, java, .net, locking

I want to lock a static method in C# , an alternate to synchronization in java .

Following is the method

```
public synchronized static  void UpdateDialListFile(String filePath, int lineno,
        String lineToBeInserted)
```

Now i am implementing this function in C# , How the alternative to synchronized will work in C#

The above method is being called from within a thread as

```
 new DialList(oDialInfo.FileName,oDialInfo.AppId,oDialInfo.AppCode,
        pausetime,oDialInfo, PropVal).start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`

you can use this if you want to synchronize the whole method.

Similar question:

[C# version of java's synchronized keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541194/c-sharp-version-of-javas-synchronized-keyword)

Comment: thanks and you mentioned if i want to synchronize whole method . what are other possible ways if i want to lock a part of method ?

Comment: look at synchronization in c#. there are many ways. depends on what you need. `lock` is one you can start with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) like this to serialize access to critical sections or resources. The scope/meaning of the guard object is entirely up to you:

```
public class Widget
{
  // scope of 'latch'/what it represents is up to you.
  private static readonly object latch = new object() ;

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    DoSomethingReentrant() ;

    lock ( latch )
    {
       // nobody else may enter this critical section
       // (or any other critical section guarded by 'latch'
       // until you exit the body of the 'lock' statement.
       SerializedAccessDependentUponLatch() ;
    }
    DoSomethingElseReentrant() ;
    return ;
  }
}
```

Other synchronization primitives available in the CLR are listed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit to lock a critical section.