# I can't figure a good design to deal with multiple calls to a blocking resource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, software-design

i'm trying to figure with the best method to deal multiple class to a method that use a blocking resource.

**The goal**:

permit the multiple calls to a method that use a `DataReader`.  While this first call is in progress, Keeping the rest to calls (if present) on hold until the method ends.

When the this method finish it's execution, i need to discard every request accumuled while the first execution was in progress, only permitting that the last request execute.

In specific i'm dealing with repeated event firing in a `Windows.Forms` object that call a `DataReader` that doesn't finish to execute and the next call that comes behind it raises an exception.

Any ideas to design this part ?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It's hard to understand what's you real problem. I suspect that you're trying to create someting like a connection pool and you can use a connection at once? Or what? ...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer ok edited my question i hope that i have explained well this time

Comment: Regarding `only permitting that the last request execute`, do you mean that if several requests are received while on execution is in progress then all but the last received request should be discarded but that last one -- also received while the first was being processed -- is processed? Let us say `R1` is received and while it is being processed `R2`, `R3` and `R4` are received in that order. Should `R4` be processed?

Comment: @MiserableVariable yeah that's rigth, but only when R1 finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If request `R1` is received and while it is being processed `R2`, `R3` and `R4` are received in that order then `R2` and `R3` should be discarded and `R4` should be processed *after* `R` processing is finished.

The pseudo-code is something like the following:

**receive request thread**

```
if current_request is null
    assign to current_request
else
    assign to next_request
```

**process request thread:**

```
while true
    if current_request is not null
        process it
        set current_request = next_request, next_request = null
```

Changes to `next_request` and `current_request` should be done using the same `lock`.

Answer (score 3):

So you have an event handler, and it's triggered repeatedly over time.  You want it to just do nothing if a previously fired handler is still running.  That's simple enough, just add a boolean "isRunning" as an instance field, and if it's true do nothing.  Just be careful to synchronize access to the variable properly:

```
private int isRunning = 0;//there is no bool overload for `Interlocked.Exchange`
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref isRunning, 1) == 0)
    {
        //do stuff

        isRunning = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //another handler is already in progress; 
        //possibly display message to user, or do nothing, or whatever
    }
}
```

If you don't want subsequent event handlers to be skipped, but you instead just want them to wait and ensure that only one is performing the query at a time then you can just use `lock`:

```
private object key = new object();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock (key)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: while i didn't choose your answer as the correct one i will award you with 50 rep (when it's available) for your answer, due to the fact you show me how to implemente the lock feature, and it's a good one

Comment: a promise is a debt. greetings

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you'd mark the method `synchronized` and all would be well.

In C#, you need to do some more work. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541194/c-sharp-version-of-javas-synchronized-keyword) for some options. The accepted answer doesn't look like the best one to me; try using the `lock` keyword first.

Comment: this will ensure that only one runs at a time; it won't cause subsequent fires to be skipped.  It's a bit unclear which is desirable from the question.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Leaving this here because `lock` might still be useful, but more work is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is best done with Reactive Extension, just use Throttle the event trigger