# Synchronization over objects in a dictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, synchronization

I have a dictionary that I maintain in C# which has a string to a class object mapping.

```
public class parent
{          
    public Dictionary<string, valueclass> clientToFileSystemMap {get;set;}
}

class valueclass
{
    //some internal state

    valueclass createclone()
    {
        create clone of this object and return
    }

    void update()
    {
        change state 
    }
}
```

Now there can be simultaneous threads which can be updating and cloning the same object at the same time. I want to synchronize the access so that clone does not return a half updated object.

One way that I found was create a private lock object in the class valueclass and acquire that lock before that operation. The other option would be to use `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` as mentioned here - [C# version of java's synchronized keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541194/c-sharp-version-of-javas-synchronized-keyword).
Another option could be to create a dictionary of objects similar to class objects and take lock on them.

What would be best way to do this?

Comment: Can you post a more specific code (in code you pasted, there is no dictionary that you're mentioning) for a better answer?

Comment: Done. Although dictionary is not really important here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to control access to the dictionary elements - but if sounds like you will need a private lock per object - as once a thread has a reference - the dictionary isn't really the issue.

```
private object privateLock = new object();

void update(){
    lock(privateLock)
    {
        //change state 
    }
}

valueclass createclone(){
    lock(privateLock)
    {
        //Clone 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes that seems to be the right option. By the way is there a specific reason why this approach is preferred over using [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] ?

Comment: Well - you actually need to use the same lock, over different methods - so, I'd suggest locking on an object.

Comment: Does [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] take the lock over this object?

Comment: @piyush Synchronized flag tells compiler to make sure only one thread is in the function at a time.  It won't prevent two treads being simultaneously on in clone second in update.  And sound like you need to make sure that synchronization occurs across both functions.

Comment: As I understand [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] would take lock over this. If I add [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] to both the methods, then access to them becomes synchronized right?

Comment: @piyush: MethodImplOptions.Synchronized is normally not recommended as it takes the lock on the object itself (i.e. on the instance of your valueclass).  This means that anybody outside the class can take a lock on the object so you no longer have control of your own lock object.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the SyncRoot provided by ICollection interface

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348148(v=vs.110).aspx